# WP_Query: "post_parent" and "post_type" combination returning strange results

Tags: wp-query, get-children

I'm experiencing some interesting results using `post_parent` along with `post_type` (local, WP 5.8):

I have a custom post type `project` (with `'hierarchical' => true`) where I'm grabbing all child posts of a parent on a single view using WP_Query.

When setting `post_type` to `project` while setting `post_parent` I get the same results as if I had not set a `post_parent` at all: that is, **I get all top-level posts with a custom post type of `project`**.

If I set the `post_type` to `any` then I get the correct child posts. I have already checked to make sure that the `$post->ID` for the parent is correct (and not 0) and that the posts are all of the same custom post type. I've also double checked the DB for weirdness and verified the parent-child relationships.

To make this stranger, this is on my local; the previous code (setting `post_parent` AND `post_type`) works fine on a live/production site (though that's on an earlier WP version).

This is the query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$projects = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $projects->have_posts() ) :
    while( $projects->have_posts() ) :
        $projects->the_post();
```

As described, if I change to `'post_type'   => 'any',` then I get the correct child post(s).

What am I missing? Is my data corrupted (though I can't see any evidence of this)...

Comment: Are the database engine or SQL versions different between live/local?

Comment: Are the posts all in the same order?

Comment: @montrealist local is MySQL 8.0.16, live is 5.7.12

Comment: @HowardE can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: If the posts are already in the order then wouldn't the results be the same?  Also, where is $post->ID coming from in this case?  Have you tried dumping your `$args` or `$projects->request` to make sure you're getting expected queries?

Comment: @HowardE still not sure what you're talking about RE: order... I'm not concerned about the post order right now. I'm concerned about which posts are being returned.

The $post->ID is coming from the single post view (in this case "single-project.php"), and yeah I've dumped those both while troubleshooting. For example, here's the request trying to get the children of post ID 1289:
`SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_parent = 0 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'project' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC`

Comment: `wp_posts.post_parent = 0` so clearly `$post->id` is not working right?

Comment: @HowardE Yes, nice catch; but if I dump `$args` I get:
`Array ( [post_type] => project [post_status] => publish [post_parent] => 1289 [posts_per_page] => -1 [orderby] => menu_order title [order] => ASC )`
I'm not sure how this would be getting messed up in between...

Comment: Does it work right if you put in your `$args`  `'post_parent' => 1289,` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129016/discussion-between-rsigg-and-howard-e).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have an errant `pre_get_posts` function:

```
function fgw_parents_only( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'project' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fgw_parents_only' );
```

Not exactly sure why `is_post_type_archive` caused this to show up on a single-project.php template, but I managed to solve this by changing the test to:

`if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'project' ) && ! is_single() ) {`